# Запустить дочерний процесс и овладеть его потоками I/O

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess

Пришлось оперативно изучать Python. Не могу решить несложную (как мне кажется) задачу: в Linux-системе запустить дочерний процесс другой программы и перенаправить ее stdin, stdout в свои, соответственно, stdout и stdin. Принципиально важно, чтобы программа жила и не умирала после единичной транзакции записи-чтения. Словом, нужно настроить длительное взаимодействие "команда-ответ" Нельзя использовать также оболочку (т.е. настройка каналов через shell), только программно.

Пишу как-то так:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['myprog', '-l'], shell = True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
#допустим, я сохранил proc и через какое-то время пытаюсь с ним взаимодействовать:
if proc.returncode == None:
    proc.stdin.write(b'command')
    response = process.communicate()[0]
```

Если запустить такой код единожды, вернет пустую строку. Если в цикле, поднимает BrokenPipeError. Такое поведение мне непонятно.

Почему такой код не работает? communicate() дожидается окончания завершения процесса? Но если это так, то почему валидна проверка `if proc.returncode == None` ? Процесс ведь жив. Что я могу сделать, чтобы это начало работать (подскажите хотя бы, что использовать)?

Comment: в сторону: 1- не используйте `shell=True`, если вы команду как список передаёте (это ошибка в большинстве случаев). Вы вероятно строку, содержащую команду хотели передать либо убрать `shell=True` 2- почему вы ожидаете что `process.returncode is not None` ДО того как вы вызвали `process.communicate()` (ПОСЛЕ возвращения этой функции `process` мёртв) 3- `process.communicate(input=b'command')` передаёт команду, закрывает stdin поток, читает вывод и ждёт пока дочерний процесс завершится, возвращая его вывод.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы интерактивно общаться с дочерним процессом удобно использовать [`pexpect` модуль](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io). Можно и напрямую вызывать `subprocess`, но это требует учёта вручную [нескольких моментов](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe), которые `pexpect` уже реализует—`subprocess` в этом смысле слишком низкого уровня для новичка (наибольшая сила, но меньше удобства).

[Пример из документации](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html):

```
# This connects to the openbsd ftp site and
# downloads the recursive directory listing.
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect('Name .*: ')
child.sendline('anonymous')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('noah@example.com')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('lcd /tmp')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('cd pub/OpenBSD')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('get README')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('bye')
```

Если вы вынуждены использовать `pexpect` это говорит, что следует поискать API для желаемой функциональности. К примеру, вместо вызова утилиты командной строки, следует вызвать функции из C библиотеки напрямую (если библиотека существует). В примере с ftp можно [ftplib модуль из стандартной библиотеки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) использовать в Питоне, вместо создания дочернего ftp процесса.