# Перенаправление вывода терминала в переменную

Tags: python, cmd

Помогите разобраться с перенаправлением вывода cmd в переменную, т.к. переменной присваивается только exit_code процесса. Для наглядности есть пара примеров:
Пример

```
import sys, os 
command = "tasklist"
result1 = os.system(command)
print(result1) # на выходе получим 0
```

Пример 2

```
command = "tasklist>temp.txt"
result2 = os.system(command)
print(result2) # на выходе получим 0
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    result2 = f.read()
    print(result2) # выведет результат выполнения tasklist
```

Вопрос: можно ли перенаправить вывод терминала windows не используя temp.txt файл, тобиш сразу выгружать значение в переменную.? sys.stdout пробовал.

```
sys.stdout = open('temp.txt', 'w') #запишет 0 в файлик 
os.system('tasklist') #сам резульат выполнения будет выведен в интеретаторе

file = open('temp.txt', 'r').read()
print(file)# выведет 0
```

Comment: Скорее это делается через subprocess. Вот тут аналогичная задача https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: такие ужасы не нужны. Можно начать с `output = subprocess.check_output('tasklist')` (если не заработает, то уже уточнять).

Comment: @jfs `output = subprocess.check_output('tasklist')` + регулярки полностью решили эту проблему, добавьте свой комментарий как ответ.

Comment: @VladimirYaremenko если это не одноразовый скрипт, то рассмотрите возможность использования API вместо regex (есть ли опции, чтобы машиночитаемый вывод получить? Есть ли библиотека/winapi, которое желаемую информацию возвращает?). Если думаете что нашли решение, которое для вас работает, то можете самостоятельно ответ оставить — [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)
— это самый простой способ получить вывод внешней команды:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['программа', 'аргумент 1', '2'])
```

Всё что `программа` выводит в стандартный вывод, сохраняется в `output`. Если программа завершится с ненулевым статусом возврата (как правило на ошибку указывает), то `check_output()` выбросит исключение (не следует неявно ошибки игнорировать).

Начиная с простого случая существует множество вариаций. К примеру, чтобы получить объединённый вывод как из стандартного потока команды (stdout) так и из потока ошибок (stderr), можно передать `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` параметр в `check_output()`. Дочерний процесс может вообще напрямую в терминал писать в обход своих stdout/stderr, в этом случае на POSIX системах можно pty создать, чтобы перехватить вывод (в таких случаях [удобно pexpect модуль использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/604835/23044)).

По умолчанию вывод возвращается в виде байт, чтобы получить текст необходимо указать кодировку символов, которая может зависеть от выбранной команды:

```
text = subprocess.check_output(['программа', 'аргумент 1', '2'], encoding=encoding)
```

Подробнее см. [Byte при печати вывода внешней команды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044).

Стоит упомянуть, что в отличии от старых интерфейсов, унаследованных из Си (таких как `system()`, `popen()`), функции в `subprocess` модуле никогда не запускают командную оболочку, если явно об этом не попросить. Что позволяет избежать [shell injection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) и делает вызов более переносимым (если сама `программа` переносима).

Comment: эх, как мне не хватало этой функции в Python 2.5 - 2.6...

Comment: @MaxU: [можно добавить `check_output()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2924310/4279)  при необходимости

Answer (score 5):

Самый простой способ перенаправить вывод из системной оболочки - это подключиться к каналу команды, вот таким образом:

```
import os

command = 'dir'
pipe = os.popen(command)

print(pipe.read())
```

Здесь мы открыли канал и получили объект открытого файла из которого можно читать или писать в него в зависимости от режима (`r` по умолчанию) открытия, используя стандартный интерфейс работы с файлами.

Comment: Запихал ваш скрипт в xterm и с трепетным удивлением обнаружил, что в Linux есть команда `dir`.

Comment: -1: не запускайте shell если это не нужно. Если `command` содержит может содержать пользовательский ввод, то это произвольную команду может запустить. Используйте: `output = subprocess.check_output([program, arg1, arg2])` вызов, который не запускает shell, если не попросите.

Comment: @jfs я по моему черным по белому написал "Самый ПРОСТОЙ способ", я разве сказал, что это именно самый безопасный метод ? зачем минусы ставить то ... Уже нельзя поделиться знаниями про os.popen ? Лишним не будет для человека.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно довольно просто получить результат выполнения как кортеж, код завершения и потоки вывода (стандартный и ошибок):

```
import subprocess

out = subprocess.getstatusoutput('xxx')
print(out)
(127, '/bin/sh: xxx: command not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

При накоплении целой кучи батников, для записи разных стримов, пришла в голову идея, автоматизировать процесс контроля за работой этих батников. Скрипт, который будет контролировать запуск и перезапуск в случае краша, мониторинг работоспособности, добавления новых стримов и оповещать в случае изменений, либо ошибок в любом из батников. Теперь собственно для чего был задан вопрос. ffmpeg иногда ругается на прямые ссылки на стримы, поэтому предварительно их нужно обрабатывать с помощью youtube-dl. Можно конечно писать все стримы youtube-dl, а потом разбивать готовые файлы на части, но они будут недоступны для просмотра во время записи.

```
# _*_coding: utf-8 _*_
import os, time, subprocess, re
from mylib import get_current_date_time, get_file_name, send_mail
from config import EXIT_CODES, STREAMS_LIST

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
FFMPEG_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ffmpeg\\bin', 'ffmpeg.exe')
YOUTDL_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'youtube-dl', 'youtube-dl.exe')
DEST_DIR = r'D:\test_dir'

if __name__ =='__main__':

    video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiBK0z6Zdf4'
    dirty_link= subprocess.check_output('{0} -f "bestvideo[height<=480]+bestaudio/best[height<=480]" -i "{1}" -g'.format(YOUTDL_PATH, video_link))
    flink_compr = re.compile(r'http.*\\n')
    FILE_NAME = get_file_name()
    out_file = os.path.join(DEST_DIR, FILE_NAME)
    dl_link = link_pattern.findall(str(dirty_link))[0].rstrip()
    command = '{0} -i "{1}" -c:v copy -vsync 1 -acodec mp2 -ac 2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 "{2}.ts"'.format(FFMPEG_PATH, dl_link, out_file)
    os.system(command)
```

UPD. Это кусочек тестового примера, через `subprocess`. Пример с `os.popen`, также работает. Но я решил уйти от батников, буду пытаться запустить несколько потоков. Удачи мне, вам всем огромнейшая благодарность )))

Comment: в качестве альтернативы запуску `youtube-dl.exe` и разбору его вывода с помощью regex, вы можете использовать youtube-dl как библиотеку. [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32072816/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```py
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> stdout = Popen('echo abc', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
>>> output = stdout.read()
>>> output
b'abc\n'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Куда еще развернутей? Что тебе осталось не понятно?

Comment: можно ориентироваться на примеры [хороших ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa%20%5bpython%5d)