# Как вывести ответ сервера на клиент

Tags: python-3.x, сокет

Есть сервер который принимает команды с мобильного устройства Android,Проблема в том что команды сервер выполняет т.е пишу с андроид tree он показывает ветку с содержимым но на телефон в консоли ветки не видно сервер просто вернул команду tree
Как сделать чтобы который выполнил команду вывел на смартфон 
[image: Скрин со стороны сервера[![скрин со стороны клиента]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCjK4.png)

Код:

```
import socket,os

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('192.168.1.100', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()


print ('connected:', addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    a = os.system(data.decode('utf-8'))
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data,a)
    print(a)

conn.close()
```

Код не мой нашел на просторах интернета

Comment: что вы ожидаете в ответе увидеть, если код не ваш? Насколько вы с Питоном знакомы и почему вы хотите его здесь использовать? Вместо этого вы можете  попробовать готовое приложение с поддержкой аналога ssh и терминал эмулятором. К примеру, termux + mosh.

Comment: Код сервера не мой,я просто дописал одну-две строчки кода,С питоном я знаком не давно,Я хочу использовать данную программу для удаленного управления своим компьютером,нет я не хочу использовать готовые я хочу понять как работают аналогичные программы !

Comment: если хотите разобраться как устроено, то начните с более простого вопроса: ["как прочитать вывод внешней команды в Питоне"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728672/23044), затем можно ["как интерактивно работать с внешней командой (посылать ввод/получать вывод, не перезапуская)"](https://goo.gl/cCFnKT), чтобы удалённо [из браузера интерактивно управлять процессом на сервере запущенном, можно websocket использовать](https://goo.gl/kfEGnb), чтобы подключаться по ssh (paramiko), обрабатывать ansi-коды (эмулятор терминала -- pyte), посмотрите как StaSh (Pythonista, iOS) реализована.