# Как отобразить вывод другого процесса в окне tkinter?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, консоль

Я новичок в библиотеке tkinter. Были проблемы с получением вывода из терминала в окно виджета. Если нажать на **кнопку** , он запускает скрипт из другого файла и показывает результат в консуле, мне нужно, чтобы он показывался в окне виджета, для этого я создал **txtarea** . Если у кого есть какие советы буду благодарен заранее.

```
#maincode.py

import os
import sys
import subprocess
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

window.title("Running Python Script")
window.geometry('550x200')


txtarea = Text(window, width=25, height=10)
txtarea.place(x=250, y=95, anchor="c")
txtarea.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")


def run():
    os.system('python hellotest.py')


btn = Button(window, text="Running Script", bg="black", fg="white",command=run)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

```
#hellotest.py

print("Hello!001 its ok,we work further")
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перенаправление вывода терминала в переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728672/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e)

Comment: там не библиотека tkinter

Comment: @Zero01, так никакой разницы нет, tkinter или нет. Берете код оттуда, кладете в функцию run, результат выполнения выводите в ваш txtarea. Всего лишь нужно соединить два куска кода, как конструктор.