# subprocess в python3. не могу передать инфу в процесс

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Пытаюсь разобраться с `Popen`

Задача такая, при подключении к удалённой машине по `sshfs` передать пароль через `communicate()`

Вот мой не работающий пример:

```
import subprocess
args =  ['sshfs', 'ubuntu@192.168.1.5:/', '~/virtual_dick' ]
process = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
password = process.communicate(input='qwerty12345')
```

Процесс запускается, но пароль всё равно требует. Что не так?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Запустить дочерний процесс и овладеть его потоками I/O](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604773/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы передать текст на вводе и прочитать вывод внешней команды, необходимо перенаправить в pipes как stdout так и stdin дочернего процесса (`Popen(.., stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)`). Можно использовать [`subprocess.check_output()` обёртку](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), которая за вас это сделает:

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output('cat', input='текст', encoding='utf-8')
'текст'
```

`encoding` параметр задаётся, чтобы указать кодировку текстовых данных (процесс принимает/отдаёт байты внутри).

Если команда завершается с  ошибкой (ненулевой код возврата), то `check_output()` выбрасывает исключение `CalledProcessError`. Чтобы изменить это поведение можно напрямую [`subprocess.run()` функцию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) вызвать или если хотите взаимодействовать с командой, пока она ещё выполняется, не дожидаясь окончания, тогда до уровня [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) можно опуститься.

Может быть вариант (вероятен, для принятия пароля), что процесс ожидает ввод не на своём стандартном вводе (stdin), а напрямую с терминала (tty). См. [Библиотека subprocess и ssh не дружат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778947/23044). И, конечно, стоит рассмотреть заход по ssh с использованием ключей, без явного ввода пароля. Например, [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/q/46930/3712)

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, в этом случае, проще всего использовать key-based аутентификацию между хостами (если есть такая возможность).

Либо посмотреть в сторону библиотеки [paramiko](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/2.3.1) для работы с SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали в конструкторе подключение к потоку ввода программы, попробуйте изменить на:

```
 process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate