# Библиотека subprocess и ssh не дружат

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, subprocess, openssh

Задача такая:
выполнить комманду `ssh -p 2356 root@192.168.43.98 echo OK`, что бы в ~/.ssh появился файлик known_hosts.

так как подключаюсь в первый раз,то должно выскочить уведомление:

> The authenticity of host '[192.168.43.98]:2356 ([192.168.43.98]:2356)' can't be established.
>   ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:c1zdKx4q0dVTg7WjhslTmYbXm2D4dX37me9u0Mm6B6A.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

после чего я должен ввести "yes", и получить known_hosts.

Пробую организовать это через subprocess на питоне:

```
import subprocess,time
args = 'ssh -p 2356 root@192.168.43.98 echo OK'.split()
go = subprocess.Popen(args,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
time.sleep(1)
go.stdin.write('yes\n')
```

однако выползает ошибка:

> ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
>   Host key verification failed.

Когда пишу это руками всё норм, а через subprocess просит какой-то ssh-askpass.
Пароль вводить не надо, хочу просто получить отпечатки.
Что я сделал не так, и как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Paramiko, и конструкцию вида

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# данная строчка решает проблему с known_hosts
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname='your_host', username='user', password='secret', port=2356)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
client.close()
```

Comment: known_hosts не появлился, хотя соединение норм прошло

Comment: @AndreyYurevich: чтобы сохранить ключи в файл, вызовите `client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))` перед `client.connect()`. Стоит заметить, что так же как и `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` команда, подключение с `paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()` подвержено MITM атаке.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` в данном случае не использует свой стандартный ввод (`stdin`), а ожидает ввод напрямую с терминала (`tty`). См. первую причину в [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

[`pty` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html) позволяет такой ввод передать, к примеру, используя [`pexpect` модуль](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html):

```
output, rc = pexpect.run('ssh ... echo OK',
                         events={b'\(yes/no\)\?': b'yes\r\n'},
                         withexitstatus=1,
                         timeout=1)
```

Если *бы* `ssh` принимал стандартный ввод здесь, то можно было бы написать:

```
p = subprocess.run(['command', 'arg 1', 'arg 2'], input=b'yes\n', timeout=1)
```

В отличие от вашего варианта, это гарантированно сбрасывает внутренний буфер и закрывает наш конец pipe, подсоединённой к стандартный вводу дочернего процесса.

---

Стоит упомянуть, что если задача пополнить `known_hosts` файл, то необязательно `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` вызывать для каждого узла. Можно вызвать `ssh-keyscan` вместо этого, чтобы для нескольких узлов сразу отпечатки получить. Так же как и ssh (при первом соединении) это подвержено MITM атаке, если не проверять валидность соответствующих ключей.