# Передача данных двумя способами

Tags: python, вывод, ввод

Можете показать пример, что значит передача данных через командную строку и через перехват ввода-вывода. И как это всё должно выглядеть в одной программе, которая в свою очередь должна вызвать ещё другие программы?

Comment: попробуйте сузить вопрос: [Python Взаимодействие с cmd.exe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/793223/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [subprocess в python3. не могу передать инфу в процесс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/769358/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, речь идет о вводе целых чисел:

```
import sys

def main():
    a = sys.argv[1] # sys.argv[0] - имя программы
    b = int(input())
```

Программу можно вызвать в командной строке: `python <имя скрипта> <параметр>`, например, `python 1.py 2`, тогда в переменную `a` будет записана двойка, в `b` будет то, что вы укажете при вызове программы.

Comment: не ясно какое это имеет отношение к вызову внешних команд: *" в одной программе, которая в свою очередь должна вызвать ещё другие программы?"*